# How to use *time.Time declared in struct of protocol buffer

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I have the following defined in a struct of my protocol buffer:

```
CurentTime    *time.Time                     `protobuf:"bytes,5,opt,name=curent_time,json=curentTime,proto3,stdtime" json:"curent_time,omitempty"
```

In my main.go code, I try to assign it like the following:
`*res.CurentTime = time.Now()`

I keep getting the following error:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x1642e61]
```

I believe I am doing assignment incorrect, but why and how do I fix this to assign properly and not crash my system ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have it

```
*res.CurentTime = time.Now()
```

Will first dereference `res.CurentTime` (that's what the `*` does here), which, if it's `nil`, will immediately panic. What comes after doesn't matter. Instead you need to assign a pointer, not assign a new value to the existing (`nil`) pointer:

```
now := time.Now()
res.CurentTime = &now
```

Answer (score 1):

Go's `time.Time` is a struct with [non-public fields](https://golang.org/src/time/time.go?s=6278:7279#L117) that cannot be sent via protocol-buffers directly.

Instead convert any `time.Time` values to google's protobuf time types.
(Under the covers this is a simple unixtime i.e. seconds since 1970 plus nanoseconds with *NO* timezone information - [see here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/timestamp.proto#L127))

For example, in your `.proto` file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

message MyData {
    google.protobuf.Timestamp   updated             = 1;
    google.protobuf.Timestamp   created             = 2;
}
```

And in your go code:

```
import (
    "time"

    "github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes"
)

// ...

updatedTime := time.Now()
updatedProto, err := ptypes.TimestampProto(updatedTime)

// ...

mydate := &pb.MyData{
    updated: updatedProto,
}
```